# Rails 3 association error: undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, associations, undefined

I've been puzzling over this for quite some time now and can't figure it out.

I've got 2 models:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :year, :capacity,
  :size, :body, :model_id, :maker_id, :parameters_attributes

    validates :year, numericality: { greater_than: 1900 }
    validates :year, :capacity, :size, :body, presence: true

    belongs_to :model
    belongs_to :maker
    has_many :parameters
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :parameters
    end
```

and

```
class Parameter < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :tag, :value
  validates :tag, :value, presence: true
  belongs_to :vehicle
end
```

in new vehicle view i've got:

```
= form_for [:admin, @vehicle], html: { multipart: true } do |f|
    =# some other stuff in between
    = f.text_field :value, size: 4
```

I get this error

```
undefined method `value'
```

Just can't seem to get it working. Help, anyone?

EDIT
routes.rb

```
resources :vehicles 
resources :parameters

resources :makers do
  resources :models
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using nested form, you should have something like

```
f.fields_for :parameters do |parameter|
```

and than:

```
parameter.text_field :value, size: 4
```

Also, remember to create the some `parameters` in the controller, for example:

```
def new
  @vehicle = Vehicle.new
  2.times { @vehicle.parameters.build } #it will create 2 parameters
...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`f` refers to `@vehicle`, it seems only `Parameter` bears this field. That's why it fails.

Sidenotes:

- In `Vehicle` you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :parameters` but you don't have `parameters_attributes` in the `attr_accessible`, can't be good.
- If you want to call the relationship in the form consider using `fields_for`

Comment: I've tried this, no longer have `undefined` error, but the `text_field` does not appear. I'm not so sure if 'accepts_nested_attributes_for` is the way, 'cause my `parameters` aren't nested within `vehicles`. I'll edit my original post, with `routes.rb` and changes I've made in models.

Comment: routes don't have any role here

Comment: use `fields_for` as I told you. If you have nothing it means you didn't build any object. Do `@vehicle.parameters.build` in your controller

Comment: I am using `fields_for`. I did `@vehicle.parameters.build` in `new` method. I got `undefined method \`parameters'`

Comment: seems you relation is unknown to rails... did you try to reboot the server?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I've made a mess of things.

Firstly I've been trying to

```
def new
  @vehicle = @vehicle.parameters.build
end
```

hence the error `undefined method`. After a while I got to the correct syntax, which is the one gabrielhilal added after a while.

```
def new
  @vehicle = Vehicle.new
  @vehicle.parameters.build
end
```

No matter ;) Still had problems, because after clicking "create" he wouldn't add records in the database. Turned out that I've set the `validates presence: true` for `tag`, but didn't assign any value to it. After fixing that, it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for all the help.

On to the next puzzle.